# jQuery text change with conditional

Tags: jquery

It's pretty basic stuff but I can't figure out the solution, from the few resources I found. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#jquery-toggle').click(function () {

    var buttontext = $('#jquery-toggle').text();

    if ($(buttontext = 'Toggled')) {
        ($('#jquery-toggle').text('Not Toggled'));
    } else {
        ($('#jquery-toggle').text('Toggled'));
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if ($(buttontext = 'Toggled'))` must be as `if (buttontext == 'Toggled')`

Comment: Ye, i didnt noticed that one, thank you very much my friend :)

Comment: hint: start using your browser console to look for errors thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is this line:

```
if ($(buttontext = 'Toggled')) {
```

- You mustn't wrap your variable into a jquery object
- `=` is an assignment, `==` or `===` is a comparison

Additionally you have superfluous parenthesis around the `.text()` function inside the condition.

`$('#jquery-toggle')` can be changed to `$(this)`, `this` will point to the element the event-handler was invoked on.

The code then would be:

```
 $('#jquery-toggle').click(function () {

        var buttontext = $(this).text();

        if (buttontext === 'Toggled') {
            $(this).text('Not Toggled');
        } else {
            $(this).text('Toggled');
        }
    });
```

Comment: missed converting a `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is with the single equal sign, which is an assignment operator (assigns a values to a variable), not a comparison operator (checks whether the two elements are equal), which is what you are after.

The following should work:

```
$('#jquery-toggle').click(function () {

    var buttontext = $(this).text();

    if (buttontext == 'Toggled') {

        $(this).text('Not Toggled');

    } else {
        $(this).text('Toggled');
    }
});
```

Note also the use of `this`, which saves you the computation of searching the document by `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if()` shouldn't have `$()` in it and needs to use a comparison operator,not **`=`**

Can shorten this by using [`text(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

```
$('#jquery-toggle').click(function () {
    // "this" is the element
    $(this).text(function(_, existingText){
       return existingText === 'Toggled' ? 'Not Toggled' : 'Toggled';
    });    
});
```